# How to change a Date Column into two separate columns, MONTH and YEAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am importing a spreadsheet that has a date column labeled `StartDate` (01/01/2000)
I need to split it into two columns one that is `Month` the other that is `Year`.

The `Month` has to be the Month Name (Jan, Feb, etc) the other is a simple 4 digit year.

I want to do this through an SSIS package.

I have tried to created a derived column using some date expressions but I can't get anything to work the way I need it to.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is the proper script to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming StartDate has a Date-ish data type and has *not* been imported as a string (DT_STR or DT_WSTR).

Add a Derived Column into your Data Flow. Give it a name, like StartMonth, and use an expression like `MONTH([StartDate])`.

Add a second Derived Column, call it StartYear and use an expression like `YEAR([StartDate])`

[image: It works]

And since I can't read, you asked for Month names. This gets a little uglier as there isn't a built in Expression functionality for this.

You could write your own using the Ternary Operatior `(test) ? true : false` but a limitation of this approach is that the expression editor is cumbersome for long expressions.

`([StartMonth]==1)?"January":([StartMonth]==2)? "February" : ([StartMonth]==3)? "March" : "Etc"`

An alternative to this is to use a Script Task. In the Rows tab, check our `StartDate` column as a readonly input. In the Output, add a new Column, named StartMonthName as type String length 3 (if you only want the 3 letter abbreviation). And if you're already using a script task, you can eliminate the Derived Column call by adding the `StartMonth` in from here.

```
Row.StartMonthName = Row.StartDate.ToString("MMM");
Row.StartMonth = Row.StartDate.Month;
```

Comment: OK, that part worked Great. Now I need to convert it to the Month Name instead of the number? The customer wants this to connect to Excel and use this data in pivot tables and doesn't want to see the month number.

Comment: My apologies on the oversight. Corrected

Comment: No worries. Thank you for the info, I will start working on this. I'm not real familiar with the Script Component just yet and have only touched on C# so I may use the ugly expression. I think I may also be able to just Cast it later in a view maybe. Thank you again for all of your help!