# How to change a Date Column into two separate columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i have an excel file that and i want to extract the date from it and load it into a dimension table but as month and year only.
I want to do this through an SSIS package.
for example i have `6/15/2002`
and i want to take only `6/2002`
because in my dimension table i have only month and year 
what should i do. please help me, it's my final project
it something like  this question

[How to change a Date Column into two separate columns, MONTH and YEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736715/how-to-change-a-date-column-into-two-separate-columns-month-and-year/43279487#43279487)

Comment: Why does the answer you posted not work for you? It describes how to use functions to pull parts out of a date exactly as you're asking.

Comment: @SirinàStrong why still not accepting LONG answer if it solved your issue? this question will still marked as Unanswered until you accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Derived Column` transformation to do that. The output from the excel source could remains as it is. Take that output through the `Derived Column` TF, add two new columns as `Add new columns`, and then the easiest way is to convert the `Date` to string `varchar` or `char` (`DT_STR` or `DT_WSTR` based on your table schema), then based on your criteria, using `substring` function to form each new column.

For example: `Derived Column 1`, `<add as new column>`, `SUBSTRING( (DT_STR, 20, 1252)Your_Column , 0, 1 ) + SUBSTRING( (DT_STR, 20, 1252)Your_Column , 6, 4 )` for your request

**UPDATED**

```
(DT_WSTR, 20)MONTH(YOUR_COLUMN)+ "/" + (DT_WSTR, 20)YEAR(YOUR_COLUMN)
```

**UPDATED 2nd**
Just like before, but for the `Derived Column 1`, `<add as new column>`, `(DT_WSTR, 20)MONTH(YOUR_COLUMN)` as  MONTH expression.

`Derived Column 2`, `<add as new column>`, `(DT_WSTR, 20)YEAR(YOUR_COLUMN)` as  YEAR expression.

You could rename `Derived Column 1` or `Derived Column 2` to any name you want for later identification.

Comment: the problem is i didn't know how to use  it this substring !!

Comment: when i use this SUBSTRING( (DT_STR, 1, 1252)date , 0, 1 ) + SUBSTRING( (DT_STR, 1, 1252)date , 6, 4 ) in my expression it comes red and won"t work.

Comment: check the data type

Comment: what i want is two columns with the name month and year. i have date that i want to divide it into those to columns. exmp 2-2017  i want 2 go the column month and 2017 to the column year !

Comment: There's no reason to convert the data to string and use substring to get this data if it's already a date. The `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions will extract these parts and also can handle different date formats.

Comment: i know i tried it but i have to write every time the whole date. why it won't do that automatically !!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by you have to write the whole date every time. You shouldn't be writing out a date anywhere, just using the column names.

Comment: @mallan1121, he is not trying to get the date part separately, did you notice `6/2002`? he has to use string concatenation to do this

Comment: @mallan1121 but when i use MONTH() and YEAR() it won't work

Comment: @SirinàStrong what is the column name that you are trying to separate?

Comment: @LONG just see the article that i put into my question and you will understand what i mean !

Comment: @SirinàStrong `date` is the column name?

Comment: @LONG the name of the column is date and i want from it just the month is another column and year also

Comment: Yes that what i want but i want the month in column and the year in another one cause in my dimension table i have month and year !

Comment: @SirinàStrong if this answer solved ur issue you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) else write ur own answer